# Newbie Question: How can I automaticaly create a model instance in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Hi Im pretty new to all this so sorry if I don't explain this very well.  I want to create a model where I can make some football projections so far I have:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name_short= models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_short

class Projection(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="projection", null=True)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('projection-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class TeamProjection(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Projection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.OneToOneField(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_plays = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

What Im trying to do is when you create a new Projection it will auto create an instance of Team Projection for each team in Team Model.

So it would be something like:

1. Projection 1  Arizona 1050
2. Projection 1  Atlanta 1020

and so on?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you created the projection.

if you use `AddView`, on form.valid you can add creation of all teams.
if you use `ModelAdmin.Add` - you can do it in model_admin.save_model()
if you made it in `RawSQL`, after creation of  Projection you can do it.

I don't know background of your project to answer more correct.